# can't override Activity transition animations on Samsung A14

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

In my app, I use `Activity.overridePendingTransition()` to customize the activity transition animations to a fade.  This works fine on all my phones... except one, a Samsung A14 running Android 14.

On that phone, the animation is nothing like the requested fade (the old screen slides up, then suddenly switches to the new screen).

Has anyone seen this on other phones?  How common is it?  Any workarounds?